# Appcelerator studio android app failed to run

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

I have installed fresh appcelerator studio and titanium CLI and also other dependancies when I am trying to run android app then it showing the following error :

```
[INFO] :   Packaging application: ../sw/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt "package" "-f" "-m" "-J" "WorkData/Appcelator Projects/test/build/android/gen" "-M" "../Appcelator Projects/test/build/android/AndroidManifest.xml" "-A" "../WorkData/Appcelator Projects/test/build/android/bin/assets" "-S" "../WorkData/Appcelator Projects/test/build/android/res" "-I" "../sw/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-23/android.jar" "-F" "../WorkData/Appcelator Projects/test/build/android/bin/app.ap_" "--auto-add-overlay" "--extra-packages" "ti.modules.titanium.ui:android.support.v7.appcompat:android.support.v7.cardview" "-S" "/var/folders/jf/f17wzygx4nbd6fg5wsntf4840000gn/T/116820-1742-1nuy1sx.xxrqp30udi/res" "-S" "/var/folders/jf/f17wzygx4nbd6fg5wsntf4840000gn/T/116820-1742-hop1bc.t53b359udi/res" "-S" "/var/folders/jf/f17wzygx4nbd6fg5wsntf4840000gn/T/116820-1742-6n4mu0.4svn3o9a4i/res"
2016-09-20T06:14:33.921Z | ERROR  | An uncaught exception was thrown!
Path must be a string. Received undefined
2016-09-20T06:14:33.922Z | ERROR  | Path must be a string. Received undefined
```

and also I am able to run same project on iPhone.

My machine Configuration is as follows :

```
Operating System
  Name                        = Mac OS X
  Version                     = 10.11.6
  Architecture                = 64bit
  # CPUs                      = 4
  Memory                      = 8589934592
Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 6.5.0
  npm Version                 = 3.10.3
Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.0.9
Titanium SDK
  SDK Version                 = 5.5.0.GA
  SDK Path                    = /Users/neosoft/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.0.GA
  Target Platform             = android
Command
```

can anyone help me to resolve issue ...

Comment: What's the location path of Android SDK on your system and also make sure that Android SDK path is correctly added in Appcelerator Studio-> Preferences... -> Studio -> Platforms -> Android?

Comment: @PrashantSaini I have checked the android sdk path and its correctly added to appcelerator studio... then also it gives same error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my Android SDK folder looks like this:

Try to look at your Android SDK folders and check if there is anything related to version 24. And also do these tasks after deleting everything related to 24 version:

- Remove the **uses-sdk** tag from **tiapp.xml** and let Titanium SDK do stuffs on its own.
- Delete **build** and **Resources** folders from your Titanium project root directory
- Clean and run the project now.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Followed your steps and also removed unnecessary folders then also I didnt get success :(

Comment: Try to create a new android project and run it without any editing. If this works, then something is wrong with your old Android project.

Comment: SDK is 5.3.1, Node is 4.2.2, NPM is 2.14.7.....also my SDK location is at root user folder on mac.

Comment: Finally worked for me, I have downgraded my node to 4.2.2 and used Titanium sdk 5.3.1.

Comment: Ahh! You got it this time.. :) ... BTW what was your node version? and you can try any Titanium SDK as I think node version could be the issue.

Comment: node : 6.5.0   SDK Version = 5.5.0.GA, Also written in question itself

Comment: Oh yes. Titanium Compatibility Matrix says to use max Node version as 4.2.x

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be using Build Tools SDK 24.#. This is not yet supported by Appcelerator. You should un-install this version and install 23 (the latest supported by appcelerator).

I recommend watching the [Compatibility Matrix](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix-section-29004837_TitaniumCompatibilityMatrix-Android) from time to time.

After that select the `minSDK` and `targetSDK` in Tiapp.xml like this:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0.0" package="app.my" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" targetSdkVersion="23"/>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

Comment: you can try downgrading it by using tiapp.xml properties. But you do need to use version 23, not 24. So 23 does need to be installed. Last time I had issues with a newer version installed thats why I recommended removing #24

Comment: ok thanks so I just need to add the above code in tiapp.xml right ?

Comment: @RenePot, yes it is correct that we cannot build using 24 currently, I had this issue this week and solved it by temporary deleting Build Tools 24 from SDK folders. So this will work.

Comment: Good to know @PrashantSaini. Agreeing is done by upvoting though on SO :)

Comment: @PrashantSaini I have deleted sdks (now using build-tools/23.0.3/)  then also it not working properly..

Answer (score 2):

Check your version of node.js with this command:

```
node -v
```

If your version is higher than 4.4.2 that's the problem. You can fix it with:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 4.4.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and got resolved after changing my node version to 4.4.2. Just updating it here if that may help anyone.